# how to get a summary of all tracked branches in git

Tags: git

When I check out a tracking branch in git, it tells me:

"Your branch is ahead of 'origin/foo' by 1 commit"

Is there a way to output this for all my branches that track a remote, eg:

"foo is ahead of 'origin/foo' by 1 commit"
"bar is ahead of 'origin/bar' by 2 commits"
...

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `git branch -v`

It should list all of your branches including whether they are ahead or behind.